# Store multiple files in one BLOB

Tags: postgresql, file, blob

I would like to store multiple files concatenated in a single BLOB in my postgresql database.

I wonder if it is possible to use the [lo-funcs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/lo-funcs.html) to perform that process or do I have to store each file size then read file by file in the BLOB to get everything back.

I considered using home-made file with the following template but it probably exists a way to do that process with proper sql calls, right ?

```
[file1 size + file1 data + file2 size + file2 data ...]
```

Any ideas or comment on my process would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Found lo_get(loid oid [, from bigint, for int]) in the documentation, but that means i have to store all sizes.

Comment: that single BLOB is one `bytea` field in one row of one table?..

Comment: @VaoTsun yes, that's my goal.

Comment: @MauricePerry i guess zip/unzip it would take time to process everytime i edit a file.

Comment: @SimonPA yes, it would.

Comment: _it probably exists a way to do that process with proper sql calls_: no, because a design that crams multiple values from multiple types into a single column plays against the relational model.